# File does not contain a valid CIL image

Tags: c#, mono-framework, opensuse-12.1

I installed mono on my Suse 12.1. When I create a file, say `hello.cs`, and run `mono hello.cs` on the terminal, I get this error:

```
Cannot open assembly 'hello.cs': File does not contain a valid CIL image.
```

The contents of the file (`hello.cs`) are as below

```csharp
class hello {
    static void main () {
        System.Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
    }
}
```

What could be the problem, and how do I solve it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `mono` command is used to run *compiled* C# programs. You need to compile `hello.cs` first with:

```
mcs hello.cs
```

Then you can execute it with:

```
mono hello.exe
```

For more information on writing C# programs with Mono see:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9407/Introduction-to-Mono-Your-first-Mono-app